# I can't get a component to display as inline-block in Angular2

Tags: css, angular

In my Angular2 app, I have a parent component, which via an ngFor loop generates a number of instances of a child component - app-video-container - which is essentially a div with an iframe inside.  I want these videos to display in a grid type layout.  I am trying to use inline-block to accomplish this, as below, but it does not work, it just displays as a single column of videos.  If I use float:left instead of inline-block, that displays the videos in a grid the way I want, but I need to able to use inline-block instead.  What am I doing wrong?  Why does float work but not inline-block?  Here is the condensed/simplified version my code:

Parent component HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let video of videos">
   <app-video-container>[videoURL]=video.videoURL</app-video-container>
</div>
```

CSS for parent component

```
:host {
     background-color:black;
     position:relative;
 }
```

App-video-container component HTML:

```
<div class="videoContainer">
    <iframe [src]="videoURL" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

App-video-container component CSS

```
.videoContainer {
width:20%;
height:100px;
margin-left:4%;
margin-bottom: 20px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Try using `display: flex` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inline-block` is not working the way you are expecting it to because you have a div wrapped around each `.videoContainer` div.

Remove the `videoContainer` class from the inner div

```
<div>
    <iframe [src]="videoURL" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

and add it to the outer div

```
<div class="videoContainer" *ngFor="let video of videos">
   <app-video-container>[videoURL]=video.videoURL</app-video-container>
</div>
```